# Why does adding a "value" attribute to an <option> element cause the wrong value to be selected?

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat

I'm using angular 1.2.28 and I have a controller with a simple array of values:

```
$scope.transTypes = ['Write-Off', 'Adjustment'];
$scope.selectedType = 'Adjustment'
```

which I use to populate a `<select>` drop-down element.

If I create my markdown like this (without 'value' attribute), then the correct value is displayed:

```
  <select ng-model="selectedType">
    <option ng-repeat="type in transTypes">{{type}}</option>
  </select>
```

When I create my markdown with a 'value' attribute, the wrong value is displayed:

```
  <select ng-model="selectedType">
    <option ng-repeat="type in transTypes" value="{{type}}">{{type}}</option>
  </select>
```

Plunker: http://plnkr.co/edit/lRqZSrxwEle3qUtT9cxi?p=preview

Comment: It would be highly advisable to use [`ng-options`](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngOptions) in such a case as yours!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i used `ng-value` in your plunker and it worked fine, it is possible that angular looked for value in the newer versions to fixes issues such as these.

Comment: Thanks, looks like that did the trick. Wondering why do I need ng- prefix on some html attributes but not others?

Comment: could you give me an example of one that works without the ng- prefix?

Comment: I can use height & width on an <img> or <div> tag without any issues.  `<img ng-src="{{image}}" height="{{h}}" width="{{w}}" />` I don't have to prefix them. Shouldn't value work the same way?

Answer (score 1):

You need to create a controller to pass the variables to the dom.
For exemple:

**HTML:**

```
<html ng-app="App">
  <body ng-controller="myController as myCtrl">

    <select ng-model="myCtrl.selectedType">
      <option ng-repeat="type in myCtrl.transTypes">{{type}}</option>
    </select>

  </body>
</html>
```

**JS:**

```
angular.module('App', [])
.controller('myController', function() {

  var _this = this;

  _this.transTypes = ['Write-Off', 'Adjustment'];
  _this.selectedType = 'Adjustment'

});
```

**You can see in action:**

http://codepen.io/anon/pen/VePZLa?editors=101

Answer (score 1):

Just rename  : `ng-value="type"` . It will work.

```
<select ng-model="selectedType">
            <option  ng-repeat="type in transTypes" ng-value="type">{{type}}</option>
          </select>
```

Answer (score 0):

I tried upgrading to the latest version of angular 1.3 but the bug remained. When I upgraded to angular 1.4, the bug seemed to go away.

Works on 1.4 : http://plnkr.co/edit/cbIRgGViOyxeQ9t3PKbK?p=preview

Its possible that older version of angular did not support setting the "value" attribute.

```
ignore this line, can't submit without code snippet.
```